# Java - Difference ((classType) this).m1() and a static reference

Tags: java, inheritance, binding

In Java one object can call the father method like this: `((Father) this).m1();` 
What is the differenc to that: `Father f = sonObj; f.m1();` ?

```
public Father extends Object {
public void m1(){}
}

public Son extends Father {
  public void m1() {
    ((Father) this).m1();
  }
}
```

Comment: I advice, you try to run your code first. Don't forget to put a print statement in both `m1()`.

Comment: no need to extend explicitly `Object` class as all classes in java implicitly extends `Object` class.

Comment: Calling `((Father)variable).m1()` will always result in son's `m1()` getting executed as in Java all methods are virtual. Your attempt to do this _within_ son's m1() will even result in infinite recursion of `Son.m1()`

Comment: are you sure? In my book, they do this. They write, that it is the same like super.m1();

Comment: In Java all methods are virtual, so you always call the method at the top of the inheritance hierarchy. When you override a method you may choose to use the super class functionality, by invoking super, but unless you do additional work inside the method there is no reason as super would have been called if you didn't override the method. Also your class hierarchy is wrong, every father is a son, so ```Father``` should extend ```Son``` not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java - Difference ((classType) this).m1() and a static reference

```
Father f = sonObj; f.m1();
```

A detail but it is not a static reference but a reference.

> In Java one object can call the father method like this:

```
((Father)this).m1();
```

> What is the difference to that:

```
Father f = sonObj; f.m1();
```

In both cases you call the `m1()` method of the instance referenced by `this` and `sonObj`.
In your example these are `Son` instances.
So the method that will call the `Son` `m1()` method.

To call the `m1()` method of the Parent class you should do it :

```
public Son extends Father {
  public void m1() {
     super.m1();
  }
}
```

Comment: ((Father)this).m1() and super.m1 is the same thank you. But why do the first works, if I want to call the parent method? I think it is still a son-object.

Comment: `((Father)this).m1()` and `super.m1()` are not the same things.  `((Father)this).m1()` calls the `m1()` method of the instance referenced by `this`. If `this` refers to a `Son` instance, `m1()` of `Son` will be called.  `super.m1()`  is an ability usable for child class to invoke the `m1()` parent method.